# How does one see the second line of status messages displayed at the bottom of an interactive job?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Sometimes on the IBM iSeries, either at the command line or inside the SEU editor, one will get error messages that are too long to display on one line of the 5250 screen (line 24 if on the command line, line 27 when inside the SEU editor).

[image]

I believe this is usually a status message like you would send with `SNDPGMMSG` or `QMHSNDPM`.  How does one read the rest of this status message?  They are not usually (ever?) written to the job log and after certain keystrokes or a refresh, they disappear.

If you move the cursor onto the line (24 or 27), you can press page up and page down to see if there are more than one separate messages, but I cannot find how to view the second line of any given message.

[image]

Is there a simple keystroke or technique that I just cannot find in the online documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your cursor down to the message line and press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

This will display additional message information:

[image]

Note this question is probably off-topic for stackoverflow...

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be the appropriate place for this question, but would it get answered there as quickly?

Comment: Ibm-midrange is available

Comment: *In principle* this question would be more suitable for either Super User or perhaps Server Fault. But *in practice*, Stack Overflow is the only Stack Exchange site which has enough IBM midrange eyeballs.

Comment: @Charles That's right, it is ibm-server on super user. There are a few AS/400 and IBM i questions there.